# How to go back to previous page without loosing any state of data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, cookies

I'm working on a web portal(on AngularJS-v1) which have something on one page and after the final submit, it redirects to next page. I'm also using D3Js for graphs and bootstrap-select for dropdowns. 
Now if a user wants to change something from previous page the data is lost. And I'm able to save the data in session storage due to which some things works but not the D3JS and bootstrap-select.
Do anyone knows what to do? I've used $cookie and ngStorage, but unable to work it out.

Comment: Did you try google? Searching "angularjs maintain state" returns 112,000 results.  Not to mention 138 posts already on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the state inside of the controller you have to store it in a service.

```
// `store` is the service which holds your data
function PageController (store) {
    this.myValue = store.myValue
}
```